# Why the external storage on simulator is in state removed?

Tags: android

I am creating App to play with storing data on the external storage, however the code doesn't work on my simulator,

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

The returned `state` is always `removed`, and below is my simulator configurations of which I set the size of the sd card as 200M, so I think the sd card should be mounted on the simulator.
[image]

do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your initialization. Well, it works. Several things you might want to try:

- Test your app on an actual device with working sdcard. Does your code give you the correct state there? That would mean, it's not the code but really the emulator.
- Use the following code in `onCreate` after the call to `super.onCreate`. It'll give you a toast showing state an actuall path to the external storage.

  ```
  Toast.makeText(
      this,
      Environment.getExternalStorageState() + ", " +
      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
  ```
- Make sure your PC has writeable space for the sd-card file. Depending on the operating system this file can be found under your `<home>/.android/avd/<device name>.avd/sdcard.img`
- Upgrade to the newest Android SDK