# SD Card (created in AVD) shows as "removed" in Emulator for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I created a virtual device with an SD card (AVD Manager->Edit the device->Advanced Settings) but my app still shows it as not there:

```
//This prints: External: removed
Log.d(TAG, "External: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState() );
```

How do I get external storage to work?

I'm using:

Android Studio 0.8.14
Device: Nexus 5, 4.4 KitKat, CPU: x86

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to creating an image for the SD card in the AVD Manager, you also need to manully edit the config file (this is a bug).

Find the emulator's configuration in your home directory:

```
#Located in:
~/.android/avd/<The_Device_Name>/config.ini
```

For example, on the Nexus 5 (created by Android Studio), it was:

```
~/.android/avd/Nexus5.avd/config.ini
```

Change the below setting to be:

```
hw.sdCard=yes
```

Comment: I have the same problem but on my AVD config.ini hw.sdCard is already setted to yes. I'm using eclipse with ADT

Comment: @jedi post a new question. yours involves eclipse, a different product

Comment: here how to solve for **eclipse**: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037723/android-studio-avd-manager-not-mounting-sd-card) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19069625/1373229)