# Android Studio AVD Manager not mounting sd card

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am using the emulator with the Nexus 5 image and when I try to access the external public storage using the following code, the storage doesn't seem to be mounted.

```
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    boolean m = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
```

This returns false. I went to the .android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/config.ini file and changed hw.sdCard to "yes" as well, but that didn't really help. Not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. I would assume the sdcard should be mounted by default.

Comment: did you give size during creation of avd?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Not sure how it happened, but I had created the emulator without specifying a SD storage size.