# sdcard in android studio emulator not know

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i'm beginner in android developing, many days i had problem with emulator-x86 in android studio and read many document for this problem, finally i found that this issue (slow emulator or not apear screen) was because my graphic display driver is PnP and i'm need to install company's version driver, not windows version!

but, i'm have new challenge!
i'm define sdcard in AVD Manager in android studio and run emulator, but emulator don't know sd card after boot!
i'm even make new sdcard (mk sdcard) and run emulator by that, but dose not work this, too.

are you have any idea?!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120754/sd-card-created-in-avd-shows-as-removed-in-emulator-for-android-studio

Comment: dear @sasikumar, your link is not my problem, i'm check my config.ini and the hw.sdCard variable is set to "yes" now!
so problem we must find problem from another place!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is stay yet!
so, i decide to explain this problem by some photo:

I made a new virtual machine:

1. I made a new virtual machine
2. And Set SD Card Option to studio managed
3. Then I run emulator, and choose Storage & USB from Setting
4. But I only can find internal storage in that!
5. You can see my config.ini here

6.and hardware setting file is here

[See this Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoQd3.jpg)

so, i do all of instructions that find in my searches, but can't solve the problem, do you see any mistake in my photos?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose let Android Studio manage SDCARD, it will not provide one. If you do not have one in the computer (android) it will not use internal memory, unlike most mobiles.
You need to choose the alternative option to set up a file to act as the SDCARD on your computer.